# I have bought bitcoin in the past but forgot which wallet it was. Anyway to find it with wallet address?

Tags: wallet-recovery

Is there any possible way? I bought it back in March, 2017 and forgot about it and now I remember I bought it in the past with coinmama but forgot which wallet it was sent to.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Bitcoin addresses conform to a standard, and that standard purposely does not include any indicator of the wallet that generated it.  As such, any bitcoin address could be generated from any wallet.

Answer (score 0):

unless you used an exchange/pool/service such as bittrex / poloniex, the answer is no.

You could always try to fill it in here -> http://walletexplorer.com and see if it returns any service, or just a generic wallet.